# No fill from server failed to load ad : 3

Tags: android, admob, ads

So I was working with AdMob and implemented a Banner and Interstitial ad. Waited more than a day but ads are not showing. It says failed to load ad : 3

The log:

```
12-17 19:20:33.680 16280-16512/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement I/Ads: App measurement is starting up, version: 13001
To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-17 19:20:33.825 16280-16280/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement 
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating 
com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
12-17 19:20:35.376 16280-16280/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement D/WebView:  
addJavascriptInterface=googleAdsJsInterface
12-17 19:20:35.899 16280-16466/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement W/Ads: Got on 
activity created
12-17 19:20:37.642 16280-16466/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement W/Ads: Got on 
activity created
12-17 19:20:40.721 16280-16466/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement W/Ads: Got on 
activity created
12-17 19:20:40.904 16280-16280/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement I/Ads: Use 
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("34A6512246BC64A9B8DC766FD114D5D5") to get 
test ads on this device.
12-17 19:20:41.056 16280-16802/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement W/Ads: Invoke 
Firebase method getInstance error.
12-17 19:20:41.057 16280-16802/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement W/Ads: The 
Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase 
integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either 
missing or out of date
12-17 19:20:42.357 16280-16280/in.shantanupatil.wamanagement I/Ads: Ad 
failed to load : 3
```

The code I used to

```
private AdView adView;
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.detail_draft_admob);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The gradle I have included

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

Also, I added the app id in the manifest. The add seems not to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check this link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en) it's not your fault.

I have same problem and it's solution is increase you app user so send ad request to admob and show your ad.

It's rule is latest rule and admob privacy make strong so apply this rule

Before 2017 it's rule is not so ad show is work fine, but right now first to send some ad request than ad show

I hope solve your question.

When apps are newly registered with AdMob, it takes some time and a few ad requests to allow inventory to build. Because of this, you may not see live impressions immediately.

Comment: After releasing several application I found that ads are displaying when I publish it on play store.

Answer (score 1):

I think.. maybe it's not your fault.
AdMob has some problem since a few months ago.
reference below links.
Many people are having the same problem. (Even AdMob seems to think they have a problem.)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/rTfuhBjGkpc

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-help-forum/8oc3pebOrFw/EicKPpUVDgAJ